# Code duplication prevention : 2 long functions differing only in inner loop

Tags: c++, templates, code-duplication

I have two functions, f_a and f_b following a general form,

```
void f_x(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++ j){
      //do loads of generic stuff
      //do stuff specific to x
    }
  }
};
```

I don't want to either (1) write the for loops more than once or (2) have a condition to check in the inner loop to determine whether to perform a- or b- specifics. One solution is to use templates as follows,

```
template <int I>
inline void specific(){}

template <>
inline void specific<0> { // do a-specific tasks }

template <>
inline void specific<1> { // do b-specific tasks }

template <int I>
void f(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
      //do loads of generic stuff
      specific<I>();
    }
  }
}

inline void f_a(){
  f<0>();
}

inline void f_b(){
  f<1>();
}
```

My questions are :

Does this seem like a fair solution?

Out of interest, is there a solution which does not use templates?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the `specific` functions being templates, just let them be normal functions and pass then in to the your generic `f` function.

Something like

```
template<typename F>
void f(F func){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
      // Generic stuff...

      // Call the specific function
      func();
    }
  }
}

void specific_x() { ... }
void specific_y() { ... }

void f_x(){
    f(specific_x);
}

void f_y(){
    f(specific_y);
}
```

Similar to your solution, but more generic as you now can pass in *any* callable object to your function `f`, including function pointers (which is used in the example above), functors, lambdas and everything else that can be called.

Comment: This solution is easier to maintain than the one proposed in the question. However, this solution may be slower as the inner call to func cannot be inlined, as the compiler will generate only one function,  f<void(*)> I believe. On the other hand, with the solution presented in the question two distinct versions of f, f<0> and f<1> will be created and inlining is possible. No?

Comment: @newling True that (compile-time) inlining is not possible with my solution (link-time inlining might still be possible), but depending on *what* the specific functions does the compiler might not be able to inline them anyway. And functions calls these days is not that burdensome that it use to be. If you have two possible solution, one that is more maintainable than the other, first go for the maintainable one unless it turns out to be a bottleneck, premature optimization and all that. :)